# FMU SDK in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, build, fmi

I was testing and creating FMUs with the tool FMU SDK provided by Qtronic. It works fine by running the script `build-fmu`, but I would like to work in Eclipse, so I can build everything from there.
So I created a new project and copied all the headers libraries that i thought would be needed, but at the end it does show a lot of undeclared functions, is there a especial way to export the files to eclipse environment?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to export FMI 2.0 for co-simulation, you could give  https://github.com/Vico-platform/fmu4cpp a try, provided that you can use cmake with eclipse.